# Expression Tokenizer

Tags: java

I'm attempting to create a tokenizer that reads an expression. When it get the token I print the type and the lexeme which is either a number of an operator. It currently prints each character individually but I need it to print double digit and decimal numbers together. Here is my code.

```
    public class Tokenizer {
String type;
String lexeme;
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
void getToken(String expression, int i) {

        if (expression.charAt(i) == '+')
        {
            type = "operator";
            lexeme = "+";       
        }
        else if (expression.charAt(i) == '-')
        {
            type = "operator";
            lexeme = "-";
        }
        else if (expression.charAt(i) == '*')
        {
            type = "operator";
            lexeme = "*";
        }
        else if (expression.charAt(i) == '/')
        {
            type = "operator";
            lexeme = "/";
        }
        else if (expression.charAt(i) == ' ')
        {
            ; //empty statement. Does nothing if the character is white space
        }
        else 
        {
            type = "number";
            lexeme = Character.toString(expression.charAt(i));
        }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    String expression = "3+66*2.5";
    Tokenizer tokenizer = new Tokenizer();
    for (int i = 0; i < expression.length(); i++)
    {
        tokenizer.getToken(expression, i);
        System.out.print("Type: " + tokenizer.type + "\t" + "Lexeme: " + tokenizer.lexeme + "\n");
    }
  }
}
```

#### Sample output - actual

```
Type: number    Lexeme: 3
Type: operator  Lexeme: +
Type: number    Lexeme: 6
Type: number    Lexeme: 6
Type: operator  Lexeme: *
Type: number    Lexeme: 2
Type: number    Lexeme: .
Type: number    Lexeme: 5
```

#### Sample output - expected

```
Type: number    Lexeme: 3
Type: operator  Lexeme: +
Type: number    Lexeme: 66
Type: operator  Lexeme: *
Type: number    Lexeme: 2.5
```

Comment: You would probably have to redesign your class, the whole thing. You have to read an unknown number of characters and store current index somewhere within the object

Comment: The question title is not a question...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I have an idea but I need you to explain.

Comment: What I'd do is make `getToken()` attempt to match 1 or more  characters at the start of `expression`, and return the number of characters "consumed". So instead of `charAt()` you would use a bunch of regular expressions, try and match them all, and pick the longest match, or the first match, or whatever. (Commonly the first amongst the longest matches wins.) At this point you're basically doing what `lex` does, modulo some decades of expanding on that basic idea.

Answer (score 3):

This statements overwrites the lexeme on each execution

```
 lexeme = Character.toString(expression.charAt(i));
```

it should be

```
lexeme += Character.toString(expression.charAt(i));
```

i.e. after identifying a single digit, add it to the lexeme.

Besides of that, your `getToken` method is not correct then by passing `i` to it you assume that a lexeme is only one character long, in fact it can be 1 or more, for example `66` or `2.5`. so you need to redesign your `Tokenizer` class. You should init the Tokenizer object with the expression then have it have a parameter-less method `getNextToken()` which makes as many iterations as needed to identify a token and then returns it. It also should have a method to check whether is there any input left, something like `hasMoreTokens()`.

Here is something you can build up on

```
public class Tokenizer {
    int pos;
    char[] expression;

    Tokenizer(String expression) {
        this.expression = expression.toCharArray();
        this.pos = 0;
    }

    enum Type { OPERATOR, NUMBER, UNKNOWN }

    class Lexeme {
        String type, token;
        Lexeme(String type, String token) {
            this.type = type;
            this.token = token;
        }
    }

    Lexeme getNextToken() {
        StringBuilder token = new StringBuilder();
        boolean endOfToken = false;
        Type type = Type.UNKNOWN;
        while (!endOfToken && hasMoreTokens()) {
            while(expression[pos] == ' ' && hasMoreTokens())
                pos++;
            switch (expression[pos]) {
                case '+':
                case '-':
                case '*':
                case '/':
                    if(type != Type.NUMBER) {
                        type = Type.OPERATOR;
                        token.append(expression[pos]);
                        pos++;
                    }
                    endOfToken = true;
                    break;
                case ' ':
                    endOfToken = true;
                    pos++;
                    break;
                default:
                    if(Character.isDigit(expression[pos]) || expression[pos] == '.') {
                        token.append(expression[pos]);
                        type = Type.NUMBER;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Systax error at position: " + pos);
                    }
                    pos++;
                    break;
            }
        }
        return new Lexeme(type.name().toLowerCase(), token.toString());
    }

    boolean hasMoreTokens() {
        return pos < expression.length;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String expression = "3+66*2.5";
        Tokenizer tokenizer = new Tokenizer(expression);
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            Lexeme nextToken = tokenizer.getNextToken();
            System.out.print("Type: " + nextToken.type + "\tLexeme: " + nextToken.token + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Type: number    Lexeme: 3
Type: operator  Lexeme: +
Type: number    Lexeme: 66
Type: operator  Lexeme: *
Type: number    Lexeme: 2.5
```

Comment: I don't think that can help me. This is suppose to be simple. The assignment is to make a Tokenizer class with a getToken() method and that is all.

Comment: @Daniel Actually this is very simple, it just corrects the design flaw in your own code and improves it a little bit, but 'simple' is relative :/ ... anyways the key is that `getToken()` - as its name says - must recognize a hole token, and a that a token kan have one or more characters. for that you have to iterate 1 or more times in that method, which it at time not does.

Comment: @Daniel I have added a basic implementation of the `getNextToken()` method (you can rename it to `getToken()` if you want)

Comment: Thanks for your effort. After reading through the code a few times I have a grasp on it. You have been a big help my friend!